# While Uninstalling windows installer using NSIS, i need to prompt a message box (Are you sure you want to uninstall.?) before the uninstaller screen

Tags: nsis

While Uninstalling windows installer from Control Panel -> Programs and Features using NSIS, i need to prompt a message box (Are you sure you want to uninstall...?) before uninstalling.

I have written the below code:

```
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

Section "Uninstall"

  ; Remove registry keys
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\EMR"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\EMR\Electronic Edition"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\EMR\Electronic Edition"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\EMR"

  ; Remove files and uninstaller
  Delete $INSTDIR\EMR_4.0.1.nsi
  Delete $INSTDIR\uninstall.exe
  
  ; Remove shortcuts, if any
  Delete "$INSTDIR\EMR\Electronic Edition\*.*"

  ; Remove directories used
  RMDir "$INSTDIR\EMR\Electronic Edition"
  RMDir "$INSTDIR\EMR"
  RMDir "$INSTDIR"
  
 RMDir /r /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR
  
SectionEnd
```

I need to display the message box something like as shown below:

Please help me on this.

Comment: I have used the function un.onInit with that i am able to pop-up the message box:  
 Function un.onInit
    MessageBox MB_YESNO "Are you sure you want to uninstall?" IDYES NoAbort
      Abort ; causes uninstaller to quit.
    NoAbort:
  FunctionEnd

Comment: You are constantly posting examples without `MUI_LANGUAGE `, you must always use `MUI_LANGUAGE ` when you are using MUI pages!

Comment: I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a uninstaller page for this:

```
...
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
```

You can use a MessageBox if you don't want a full page:

```
Function un.onInit
MessageBox MB_YESNO "Are you sure you want to uninstall $(^Name)?" /SD IDYES IDYES NoAbort
Abort
NoAbort:
FunctionEnd
```